# setVisible(false) removes marker but not setMap(null)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API V3 to place some markers on a map. Because there may be overlapping markers due to more than one marker having the same LatLng, I am trying to remove all the overlapping markers except the first one using `setMap(null)` and `setVisible(false)`.

**Problem:** When `setMap(null)` is used on the marker, the function does not seem to do anything and the marker remains on the map. However if `setVisible(false)` is used, the marker does indeed disappear.

Any idea why does this happen?

I also notice that the marker clusterer plugin used did count all the duplicate markers that have already been `setVisible(false)` and `setMap(null)`,

**JS Code**

```
$.getJSON(getJSON_url, 
    {
        someValues: someValues
    }, 
    function(json){

        for( i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

            // Check if marker already exist at that LatLng
            var duplicate_marker = 0;
            for( var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                // If marker exists
                if( json[i].lat == markers[j].getPosition().lat() && json[i].lng == markers[j].getPosition().lng()) {   
                    console.log( json[i].lat + ' ' +  json[i].lng + ' ' + i + ' ' + markers[j].getPosition().lat() + ' ' + markers[j].getPosition().lng() + ' ' + j);
                    duplicate_marker = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Place markers on map
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].lat, json[i].lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                icon: base_url + 'images/template/markers/listing.png',
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);

            // Make duplicate marker invisible
            if(duplicate_marker) {
                //marker.setMap(null);
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
```

Comment: Why just do not create duplicate markers? Or at least create marker without `map` parameter and set it later, after checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the use of a clusterer. The clusterer shows and hides the individual markers by calling setMap, so it is likely overriding your call to setMap(null). But since it respects setVisible that keeps them from appearing. Either remove the duplicate markers from the clusterer or dont create them at all